# Python with C++: CUDA, cuSPARSE compilation gives an undefined symbol error

Tags: python, c++, libtorch

My goal is to run a Python function calling C++/CUDA functions, which use cuBLAS and cuSPARSE.

First, I compile a custom library using *setuptools* with no errors. Then, I run a python script that imports the library. After that, I get the following error: `undefined symbol: cusparseCreateDnVec`. This library also uses the cuSPARSE function: `cusparseCreateDnMat` with no problems.

These are my NVIDIA settings: `NVIDIA-SMI 470.57.02    Driver Version: 470.57.02    CUDA Version: 11.4`

**As suggested by *unddoch***:

```
$ ldd pytorch_custom_cuda.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd7ffdd000)
        libc10.so => not found
        libcudart.so.11.0 => /usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64/libcudart.so.11.0 (0x00007fe258c82000)
        libtorch_cuda.so => not found
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe258aa0000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe258a85000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe258893000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe258f5a000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe25888b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe258868000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe25885d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe25870e000)
```

After running:

```
$ setup_debug.py install
$ python min_repr_ex.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "min_repr_ex.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pytorch_custom_cuda
ImportError: /home/my_username/my_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_custom_cuda-0.0.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/pytorch_custom_cuda.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cusparseCreateDnVec
```

These are the files needed to run this example:

```
min_repr_example_folder
|  min_repr_ex.py
|  min_repr_example.cpp
|  setup_debug.py
```

min_repr_example.cpp

```
#include <ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.h>
#include <torch/extension.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h> // cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy, etc.
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <cusparse.h> // SpMM, SpMV

void foo() {
    float vals[] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
    float *gpu_vals;
    cusparseDnMatDescr_t matA;
    cusparseDnVecDescr_t vecX;

    cudaMalloc((void**) &gpu_vals, 4 * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(gpu_vals, vals, 4 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cusparseCreateDnMat(&matA, 2, 2, 2, gpu_vals, CUDA_R_32F, CUSPARSE_ORDER_COL);
    cusparseCreateDnVec(&vecX, 4, gpu_vals, CUDA_R_32F);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(TORCH_EXTENSION_NAME, m) {
  m.def("foo", &foo, "example function");
}
```

min_repr_ex.py

```
import torch
import pytorch_custom_cuda

print(":)")
```

setup_debug.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension

setup(
    name='pytorch_custom_cuda',
    ext_modules=[
        CUDAExtension('pytorch_custom_cuda', [
            'min_repr_example.cpp'],
            extra_compile_args={'nvcc': ['-lcublas', '-lcusparse']}
        )
    ],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': BuildExtension
    })
```

Comment: Please run `ldd pytorch_custom_cuda.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Just added that to my question. I see where's the error comming from but I don't know what else to do to fix it.